# react warning computedMatch regarding some case issues?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have props named as isAuthenticated and it also shows that some case warning persists in my console. Please check it.

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import LogoutHome from './Logout_Home';
import SignIn from '../Components/SignIn';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import {setCurrentUser} from '../actions/authActions';
import SignUp from '../Components/SignUp';
import setAuthToken from '../util/setAuthToken';
import AboutUs from '../containers/AboutUs';
import store from '../store';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
// check for TOKEN
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);
  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());

    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = '/login';
  }
}
class HomePage extends Component
{
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated);
  }
    render(){
      var {
        isAuthenticated
      } = this.props.auth;
      return(
        <div>
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Switch>
                {this.props.auth.isAuthenticated===false ? (
                  <div>
                  <Route exact path='/' component={LogoutHome}/>
                  <Route  path='/Finance/Login' component={SignIn}/>
                  <Route  path='/Finance/AboutUs' component={AboutUs}/>
                  <Route  path='/Finance/ContactUs' component={ContactUs}/>
                  <Route  path='/Finance/SignUp' component={SignUp}/>
                  <Route  path='/Finance/Forgotpassword' component={Forgotpassword}/>
                  </div>
                  ) : (
                    <div>
                  <Route  path='/Finance/Home' component={Home}/>
                  </div>
                  )}
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    auth : state.auth
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage);
```

And the warning is some like this:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: React does not recognize the `computedMatch` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `computedmatch` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in div (at Homepage.js:50)
    in Switch (at Homepage.js:48)
    in div (at Homepage.js:47)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at Homepage.js:46)
    in div (at Homepage.js:45)
    in HomePage (created by Connect(HomePage))
    in Connect(HomePage) (at App.js:10)
    in div (at App.js:9)
    in App (at index.js:10)
    in Provider (at index.js:9)
```

I am not understanding weather it's case issue or what because I read it at many place but different answers I am getting. Above pasted is homepage component only.

Comment: show `Homepage` component.

Comment: Above posted is HomePage component only. Please check updated question.

Comment: Ok.. Read this [blog](https://medium.com/@clickclickonsal/i-learned-react-fragments-6db6d482cb1c) . It has the answer for you.. :) those `<div>` are culprit inside `<Switch>`, use `Fragment` to solve the issue.

Comment: No need for <div> above Switch. Also inside Switch.

Comment: @RaviTeja he needs something there but not `<div>` or any html dom.. But `<>` or `<Fragement>` will solve this.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From React [doc](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html)

> The unknown-prop warning will fire if you attempt to render a DOM
>   element with a prop that is not recognized by React as a legal DOM
>   attribute/property. You should ensure that your DOM elements do not
>   have spurious props floating around.

Inside the [`<Switch>`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/46c4c530e0ba1d159ea11310f4c5bdad8da80322/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js#L68) component, you will see the below line.

```
React.cloneElement(child, { location, computedMatch: match })
```

In this case, the `child` is your `<div></div>`, so a non standard props `computedMatch` are being passed to native dom node `<div>`, thus React gives you an healthy warning. So, using `<>` or `<Fragment>` will discard the warning.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more explanation to your workaround?

Answer (score 13):

As others have said, the issue comes from having a `<div>` directly inside of a `<Switch>` element.  From the [documentation for `<Switch>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch):

> All children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements.

So while you apparently can get rid of this error by wrapping your element in a fragment tag, it's more in-line with the intended usage to wrap it in a `<Route>` element instead.

A `<Route>` with no props should provide the intended behavior.

Comment: 100% correct ... also you can use <> to wrap them

Answer (score 10):

I solve that issue **remove** `<div>` tag inside the  tag. or **replace** `<div>` with `<React.Fragment>`.

in this case :

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import LogoutHome from './Logout_Home';
import SignIn from '../Components/SignIn';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import {setCurrentUser} from '../actions/authActions';
import SignUp from '../Components/SignUp';
import setAuthToken from '../util/setAuthToken';
import AboutUs from '../containers/AboutUs';
import store from '../store';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
// check for TOKEN
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);
  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());

    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = '/login';
  }
}
class HomePage extends Component
{
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated);
  }
    render(){
      var {
        isAuthenticated
      } = this.props.auth;
      return(
        <div>
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Switch>
                {this.props.auth.isAuthenticated===false ? (
                  <React.Fragment>
                  <Route exact path='/' component={LogoutHome}/>
                  <Route  path='/Finance/Login' component={SignIn}/>
                  <Route  path='/Finance/AboutUs' component={AboutUs}/>
                  <Route  path='/Finance/ContactUs' component={ContactUs}/>
                  <Route  path='/Finance/SignUp' component={SignUp}/>
                  <Route  path='/Finance/Forgotpassword' component={Forgotpassword}/>
                  </React.Fragment>
                  ) : (
                    <React.Fragment>
                  <Route  path='/Finance/Home' component={Home}/>
                  </React.Fragment>
                  )}
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    auth : state.auth
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage);
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue with `react-router-dom` because I placed a `div` inside my `Switch`. Instead, I moved my `div` outside of my `Switch` and the error is gone.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple, just add another layer of `<React.Fragment>` after `<Switch>`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, Container was creating an error ComputedMatch:

```
return (
    <>
        <SearchAppBar/>
        <Switch>
            <Container sx={{ mt: '3rem', maxWidth:'95%'  }} maxWidth={false}  >
                <Route path='/questionlist' render ={() =>  <QuestionList/> }/>
                <Route path='/newquestion' render ={() =>  <CreateQuestion/> }/>
                <Route path='/basequestion' render ={() =>  <BaseQuestion/> }/>
                <Redirect to = '/questionlist' />
            </Container>

        </Switch>

    </>
```

I did this and everything is ok:

```
return (
    <>
        <SearchAppBar/>
        <Container sx={{mt: '3rem', maxWidth: '95%'}} maxWidth={false}>
            <Switch>

                <Route path='/questionlist' render={() => <QuestionList/>}/>
                <Route path='/newquestion' render={() => <CreateQuestion/>}/>
                <Route path='/basequestion' render={() => <BaseQuestion/>}/>
                <Redirect to='/questionlist'/>


            </Switch>
        </Container>
    </>
```